# Android NDK and Cygwin configuration issue

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a problem configuring my system for using the NDK over Windows. Those are the step I made:

- Installed cygwin.
- Downloaded the NDK
- Added to windows path:

  - path to: cygwin\bin
  - path to sdk\tools
  - path to sdk\platform-tools
  - path to ndk
- Installed CDT plugin for eclipse

Then in Eclipse I opened the project properties and in the build command I put "ndk-build". And the console shows that error:

```
Cannot run program "ndk-build": Launching failed             C/C++ Problem
```

I suppose that is because is trying to execute the ndk-build file over the windows cmd, without using the cygwin. How can I solve that?

Note: if I open a cygwin bash and type ndk-build -version it returns the version info but if I try to execute it in the standard cmd console it returns

```
'ndkbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to prepend "bash" before the path to ndk-build in the project properties. So if you installed your NDK on C:\ put

```
bash C:\android-ndk-r6\ndk-build
```

in the build command field.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out that you no longer need Cygwin to run ndk-build with the recent versions of NDK. You still need it for debugging native code, though.